# How can I call an Activity from Fragment.kt file?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, kotlin

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var tvhelpcenter: TextView
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
        /*  val view = inflater?.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_home,
              container, false
          )*/
        /*val tv_help_center: TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.tv_help_center)
        tv_help_center!!.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().run {
                startActivity(Intent(this, HelpCenterActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: startActivity(Intent(activty, HelpCenterActivity::class.java))

Answer (score 5):

You should use **`activity!!`** instead of **<s>this</s>** here.

For Fragment use -> <kbd>**activity!!**</kbd>

```
 activity!!.startActivity(Intent(activity!!, HelpCenterActivity::class.java))
 finish()
```

**2nd Approach**

```
   (activity as MainActivityName)?.let{
       val intent = Intent (it, HelpCenterActivity::class.java)
       it.startActivity(intent)
       finish()
    }
```

> [**`let`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)->takes the object it is invoked upon as the parameter and returns
>   the result of the lambda expression.
>
> **`it`**->keyword contains the copy of the property inside **`let`**.

Comment: Please avoid using `!!`. `activity` can be `null`, so do a proper nullcheck!

Comment: I downvoted this, because it encourages bad programming habits that go against Kotlin code conventions. As mentioned in my previous comment, proper nullchecks should be favored over `!!`. Moreover, `activity` is of an optional type for a very good reason, thus a nullcheck here is a *must*. Therefore, I think of this as of an incorrect answer, which I downvoted. It is my opinion, and I have no problem removing the downvote, once the code conforms to the good practices of Kotlin conventions.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng `once the code conforms to the good practices of Kotlin conventions`. Check edited answer. Hope this good practice. Learn from last mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the parent Activity:

   val intent = Intent (getActivity(), Main::class.java)
    getActivity().startActivity(intent)

   2. or do like this

   activity?.let{
       val intent = Intent (it, Main::class.java)
       it.startActivity(intent)
   }